# Redirecionar para uma página passando um objeto

Tags: php

Preciso passar um objeto para uma página. Por exemplo: Eu gostaria que no momento que eu redirecionasse para uma determinada pagina que apresentará o html, que nela eu pudesse recuperar esse objeto e usar o que estiver nele.

Alguém teria um exemplo de como fazer isso?

Esse é um exemplo que fiz para tentar explicar melhor:

```
<?php

include_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/exemplomvc/src/model/to/CadastroTO.php';
include_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/exemplomvc/src/model/cadastro.php';

class CadastroController {

    private $cadastroTO;
    private $cadastro;

    public function __construct() {

        $this->cadastroTO = new CadastroTO();

        $this->inicializa();
    }

    /*
     * 
     */
    public function inicializa() {

        $codigo = (int) $_POST['codigo'];
        $nome = (String) $_POST['nome'];

        $this->cadastroTO ->setCodigo($codigo);
        $this->cadastroTO ->setNome($nome);

        $this->cadastro = new Cadastro($this->cadastroTO);    

        try {

            //variável a ser passada para a pagina.
            $dados = $this->cadastro ->consultar();

            header("Location: " . $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/exemplomvc/index.php');

        } 
        catch(CadastroException $erro) {

           echo $erro ->getMessage();
        }
    }
}

$obj = new CadastroController();
```

Quando essa classe for chamada, ela redirecionara para uma pagina que apresentara o html, e nessa pagina eu gostaria de recuperar essa variavel "$dados" que contém uma instancia da classe com os gets e sets.

Seria a melhor forma iniciar a variável de sessão?

Comment: Pode usar sessão ou um input hidden caso sejam poucos valores. Mostre o código que já fez.

Comment: Dá pra fazer com javascript. Se quiser, usa JSON. Se não, com php basta salvar o dado dentro de uma Session, que aí se for usar em mais de uma página (ou em páginas não consecutivas, no futuro), não precisa ficar passando os dados via form.

Comment: Adicionei mais detalhes, inclusive a classe de exemplo para explicar melhor.

Seria uma boa solução iniciar uma variável de sessão?

Comment: Procure ler sobre Query string, acho que pode te ajudar.

Comment: Pode parecer uma pergunta estúpida, mas a quê exatamente você se refere com **redirecionamento**? Pelo código, nenhum está sendo feito e, sem essa informação, não apenas sua pergunta fica sem sentido, como podemos acabar respondendo algo que faz menos sentido ainda.

Comment: Olá @BrunoAugusto

No final do try eu gostaria de executar um header:

header("Location: " . $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/exemplomvc/index.php');

E em index.php onde foi redirecionado gostaria de recuperar a variável "$dados". A variável "$dados" contém um array de objetos.

Comment: Você tem duas saída, então. Armazenar o objeto da propriedade **cadastro** em uma sessão **e** [gravá-lo imediatamente](http://www.php.net/session_write_close) e só então redirecionar -OU- resolver todo problema nesse método, dessa classe e só redirecionar se houver um sucesso, afinal de contas essa é uma das funções do bloco try.

Comment: ao invés de redirecionar, acho que poderia fazer um include..
sendo assim, o objeto seria acessível no script dentro de "/exemplomvc/index.php".. Claro que não sei o que há nesse index.php... aí vc que deve avaliar... Opinião pessoal, eu evitaria esse redirecionamento da forma como está.. Acho desnecessário e apenas consome mais requisição ao server, apesar de ser pouca coisa, mas consome..

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar como parêmetro o objeto a ser passado, no método que faz redirecionar para a pagina e capturar. Eu uso geralmente uma classe view que sempre chamo no controlador.

Exemplo:

```
/**
 * Description of View
 *
 * @author Francisco Nascimento
 * @email d19sp.webdeveloper@outlook.com
 */
class View  extends Atributos{
    #Armazena o Conteudo html da view
    private $_Contents;

    #armazena o arquivo html,tpl,phtml

    private $_view;
    #Armazena os parametros a serem mostrados na view

    private $_parameters;

    #PASSA MESSAGE


    public function __construct($_view = NULL, $_parameters = NULL) {

        if($_view != NULL){

            $this->setView($_view);

            $this->_parameters = $_parameters;


        }
    }
        /**
       * Define qual arquivo html deve ser renderizado
       * @param string $st_view
       * @throws Exception
       */
        public function setView($view){

            if(file_exists($view)){

                $this->_view = $view;

            }else{

                $_view = PATH_INCLUDE."404.php";
                $this->setView($_view);
            }
        }

        /**
        * Retorna o nome do arquivo que deve ser renderizado
        * @return string 
        */

        public function getView(){

            return $this->_view;
        }

        /**
        * Define os dados que devem ser repassados é view
        * @param Array $v_params
        */
        public function setParameters(array $_parameters){

            $this->_parameters = $_parameters;

        }

        /**
        * Pega os dados que foram passados como parametro para a pagina
        * @return Array
        */

        public function getParameters(){


            return $this->_parameters;
        }

        /**
        * Retorna uma string contendo todo 
        * o conteudo do arquivo de visualização
        * 
        * @return string
        */

        public function getContents(){

           ob_start();


           if(isset($this->_view)){

                require_once($this->_view);


           }

           $this->_Contents = ob_get_contents();

           ob_end_clean();

           return $this->_Contents;
        }

         /**
         * Imprime o arquivo de visualização
         */

         public function showContents()

         {
             echo $this->getContents();


         }



}

      class ListaController{

             public $_view;

             public function CompararItemAction()
             {
                 # Verifica se o usuario esta logado

                 Functions::is_logado();

                # Instancia para pegar o parametro id da url

                $app = Registry::getInstance("Application");

                # Retorna o id da url
                $id = $app->getParam('srcid');

                # Array para receber os dados dos produtos
                $produtos = array();

                # Atribui os dados dos produtos e dos mercados no array

                $produtos['Produtos'] = $this->getProdutosLista($id);
                $produtos['mercados'] = $this->getMercados();



                /* $produtos é um array de objetos passado como parametro
                   no meu caso ja tenho um netodo para capturar os dados
                   atribuidos para $produtos a idéia é mostrar como passar o parametro
                   para a view

                   a classe View recebe dois parametros, a pagina a ser mostrada e os parametros a ser exibido na pagina
                */
                # Chama a pagina Correspondente

                $this->_view = new View(PATH_VIEW . "Lista_CompararItem.phtml",$produtos);
                $this->_view->showContents();

         }
    }
```